# Thresholds for tag wiki editing set too high?

Tags: discussion

For an extant tag wiki:

> To edit this wiki, you must have at least 2000 reputation and hold the bronze [tag badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags) for this tag.

To begin a tag wiki:

> Tag wikis can be edited by users with more than 1500 reputation, provided:
>
> - They are in the top 20 answerers for this tag
>
>   or
> - They hold the bronze tag badge for this tag

For such a (relatively) young, small and low-traffic site, those thresholds seem a bit high.  At the time of writing, there are only 35 users with rep ≥ **1500**, 25 with rep ≥ **2000**, and 6 with tag badges.  Hardly in the “wiki” spirit?

Comment: It’s not just “hardly in the wiki spirit”; it’s also counter-productive!  If there are only 6 people able to do something which takes a fair bit of somewhat dull work and is comparatively non-urgent, then it probably won’t get done.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the inconsistency the other day. I agree, the high threshold makes it quite painful to improve these wikis.

We are in the process of implementing a system that allows low rep users to "suggest" edits to existing wikis. Once these edits are "vetted" by users with full edit rights, they will go live.